# WordPress: How to change posts per page on admin category list

Tags: wordpress

I would need to set a custom value for items per page on /admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category.

Default value is 20, I would need to set 500.

Sure, user can override this value by manual setting but I would need to set it programatically for all admin users.

I tried pre_get_posts filter but it seems it's not the right one.

Is there any way, how to change it in function.php file, please?